Rewriting the inequalities that describe a Matroid polytope
Consider the following description for a Matroid polytope:
$$P_n({z_I})=\{(t_1, \dots, t_n) \in \Bbb R^n: \sum_{i=1}^n t_i=r, \sum_{i \in I} t_i \leq r(I), \forall I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n \} \}$$
From where $r$ represents the rank of the Matroid M(wich is described by $E$ finite set, and his colection of basis $\mathcal{B}$), actually I want to see as a step from
$$\sum t_i \leq r(I)$$
to
$$\sum_{i \in I} x_i = \sum_{i \in [n]} x_i-\sum_{i \in [n]-I} x_i \geq r-r([n]-I)$$
I think that is really important consider this property of the rank:
$$r(X \cup Y)+r(X \cap Y) \leq r(X)+r(Y)$$
But is not very clear for me, can you give a little hint or something like that?, I'll appreciate any help!
